# Implicitly copied constructor Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Node{
    int value;
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> createListNodes(int min, int max)
{
    // odered vector with i.e. {0,1,2,3,4}
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> alternative;
    if (min == max)
    {
        alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(min,nullptr,nullptr)); // it is a leaf node
        return  alternative;
    }
    for (int i=min; i<=max; i++)
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> left = createListNodes(min,i-1); // for the left side
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> right = createListNodes(i+1,max); // for the left side
        if (left.size() == 0) // if node i has just one child and it is in the right
        {
            for (auto elem_right : right) // ERROR
            {
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i,nullptr,elem_right));
            }
        }
        else if (right.size() == 0) // if node i has just one child and it is in the left
        {
            for (auto elem_left : left) // ERROR
            {   
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i,elem_left,nullptr));
            }
        }
        for (auto elem_left : left) // ERROR
        {
            for (auto elem_right : right) // ERROR
            {
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i,elem_left,elem_right));
            }
        }
    }
    return alternative;

}

int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> combinations = createListNodes(0, N);
}
```

I am receiving an error when iterating over the vector of unique_ptr but I do not manage to understand the real problem. I have tried as well moving the unique_ptr to the vector alternative but the problem still persists.

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Node,
      std::__1::default_delete<Node> >'
            for (auto elem_left : left)
```

Comment: Well, you can't copy a `unique_ptr`. Iterate with a (constant) reference. Also `elem_left` and `elem_right` are `std::unique_ptr<Node>` not `Note*`, so think if `Node` should store a pointer `Node*` or better you should be working smart pointers that can be shared between objects `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: How would you do that? If I iterative using a counter and doing element_right[i] works but it is not the clean

Comment: You are also going to have to decide how multiple `Node`s are meant to all uniquely own the same children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like:

You have several issue, you iterate over copy, instead of reference.

lifetime of inner nodes stop at each loop iteration.

You can make nodes own its children:

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right = nullptr;

    Node(int v, std::unique_ptr<Node> left = nullptr, std::unique_ptr<Node>right = nullptr) :
        value(v), left(std::move(left)), right(std::move(right))
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<Node> DeepCopy() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<Node>(value,
            left ? left->DeepCopy() : nullptr,
            right ? right->DeepCopy() : nullptr);
    }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> createListNodes(int min, int max)
{
    // odered vector with i.e. {0,1,2,3,4}
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> alternative;
    if (min == max)
    {
        alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(min, nullptr, nullptr)); // it is a leaf node
        return  alternative;
    }
    for (int i=min; i<=max; i++)
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> left = createListNodes(min, i-1); // for the left side
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> right = createListNodes(i+1, max); // for the left side
        if (left.size() == 0) // if node i has just one child and it is in the right
        {
            for (auto& elem_right : right)
            {
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i, nullptr, std::move(elem_right)));
            }
        }
        else if (right.size() == 0) // if node i has just one child and it is in the left
        {
            for (auto& elem_left : left)
            {   
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i, std::move(elem_left), nullptr));
            }
        }
        for (auto& elem_left : left)
        {
            for (auto& elem_right : right)
            {
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i, elem_left->DeepCopy(), elem_right->DeepCopy()));
            }
        }
    }
    return alternative;
}
```

[Demo (with `std::unique_ptr`)](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5b480ab4bfb9a1a)

[Demo (with `std::shared_ptr`)](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c21160d6c332e978)

Comment: I was about to comment about the unsafety of all those `get`s, but then I realised everything is owned by the return value. Still unsafe if you add or remove elements to it

Comment: but this is not what I want to do: what I want to do is to create all possible combinations of a binary search tree

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos: revised my answer to have expected behavior.

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid the deep copy by just moving the child pointers to the left and right of their father? As I do not care about         std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> left = createListNodes(min, i-1); // for the left side 
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> right = createListNodes(i+1, max);
I just want to save the different connections along the tree so the father can have all information from the children

Comment: We use `std::unique_ptr`, so unique ownership, so node should belong to only one parent node (or to the vector which owns roots). With `std::shared_ptr`, you might do a light copy (care then than modifying one sub-tree change all trees containing that sub-tree).

Comment: yeah but I was thinkin that as every node is independent (is not shared) we could do something like:
                alternative.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(i, std::move(elem_left), std::move(elem_right)));

But I am getting the same number of combinations but some of the point to null and I do not figure out why

Comment: It would be a way not to copy by value the left and right but to move it to the parent, sparing some operations

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos: `deepCopy` removed when used only once. but still required in general case. `shared_ptr` allow indeed less copies. Demo updated for both.